# An unexpected error occurred in Report Processing. Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rdlc

[image]

while executing the local report sometimes it gives **Index was outside the bounds of the array exception** and when I restart the application it is working fine

sometimes I got this exception not every time

Comment: It is recommended that you can debug it so that you can see the subscripts that are out of bounds. In addition, after you restart the program, does the error appear?

Comment: Known bug. https://github.com/amh1979/AspNetCore.Reporting/issues/16